# How to read HOCON config to load values into Map?

Tags: java, hocon

I have a config as mentioned here

```
map-config{  
      key1 : [ list1, list2, list3 ],
      key2 : [ list4, list5 ],
      key3 : [ list6 ]    
   }
```

Once after loading I except it have a Map with keyset as `key1`, `key2` and `key3`
whose corresponding values will be a list with `list1, list2, list3`, `list4, list5` and `list6`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't find direct method call but the following piece of code can help me store configuration values in `Map<String, List<String>>`

```
private static void method(Config config) {
    for( Entry<String, ConfigValue> element : config.entrySet()){
        String key = element.getKey();
        map.put(key, config.getStringList(key));
    }
}
```